# Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent with another flavor

Tags: java, android, android-intent, securityexception, android-productflavors

I'm working on an application that has 2 flavors, free and pro. The free seems to work fine but when i try to go from the preference activity Settings to the activity names It appears this error:

```
-12 00:41:49.473  18533-18533/com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded.Pro E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded.Pro, PID: 18533
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded/.NameList } from ProcessRecord{9f48ed8 18533:com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded.Pro/u0a59} (pid=18533, uid=10059) not exported from uid 10060
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2611)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1502)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3825)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3785)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4100)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4068)
        at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:1012)
        at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:214)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:309)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3899)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
```

The structure of my module is something like this:

```
src
  -debug
      -java->package->Namelist
  -main
      -java->package->SettingsDuel
                      NameListStructure(A class that extends arrayAdapter, i use it to show the list in a format i want)
  -pro
      -layout->mainscreen(used in Dhmain)
  -prodebug
      -java->...DHMain
  -prorelease
      -java->...DHMain
  -release
      -java->...NameList
```

Didn't show the free version structure as i dont think its necessary, its working fine.

NameList is in both debug in release, they both have minor changes and i created that directory so i dont need to have a copy in the free/pro directories.

DHMain changes depending if its free/pro and debug/release.

SettingsDuel is in main only and it never changes.

I access the activity NameList through SettingsDuel this way:

```
<Preference
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/Names">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded"
            android:targetClass="com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded.NameList"/>
    </Preference>
```

This is in an xml file in the main directory, it never changes. Also its the only way to access the NameList activity.

And finally, the appid changes according to the app flavor (i think this could be causing the problem because the free version doesnt change its id and it works fine):

free:

```
applicationId 'com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded'
```

pro:

```
applicationId 'com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded.Pro'
```

I've tried the following:

-Add android:exported="true" in class SettingsDuel.

-Add android:exported="true" in class NameList.

-Add android:exported="true" in class Both classes.

-Add the class NameList to the pro packages (prodebug and proRelease)

-Cleaning the project.

-Rebuild project.

At this point i dont know what else to try.

**EDIT:**

After doing what Minhtdh told in his answer it sort of worked. The activity NameList works ONLY if i have the free version installed to.

If i try to access activity NameList with the pro version only it shows this error:

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded/com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded.NameList}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1782)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3825)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3785)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4100)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4068)
        at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:1012)
        at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:214)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:309)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3899)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
```

It says it cant find the activity NameList even if though i have it in the manifest (the manifest is in the main directory):

```
        <activity
        android:name=".NameList"
        android:label="@string/Names"
        android:exported="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded.SettingsDuel" />
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is: your pro version is trying to start an service in free version.
And from your description, I guess you only rebuild the pro version, right?
If that true, you should try this:

- Add android:exported="true" in class NameList.
- Then rebuild and install **free version**.
- Then run and test with the pro version.

Hope this works.
 **Update**
Your free version app id is `com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded` 
and pro version is `com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded.Pro`
Because of the intent in `SettingsDuel` preference:

```
<intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded"
        android:targetClass="com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded.NameList"/>
```

That intent will try to open activity from the free app (class name and action are same in both apps, but the `targetPackage` retrict intent to open free version only) 
 -> So when open from pro app, you will have permission error (due different process) or `activitynotfound` if don't install free app.

If you want to open the activity from pro version, just use different `targetPackage` for each app.(for pro version use `android:targetPackage="com.albertoha94.apps.DuelHelperReloaded.Pro"`)

Comment: Yea, i was rebuilding the pro version. It seems to work so far! :D
Can you explain me pls what exaclty happened? Why the app suddenly "has permission" and do i need both apps on the phone to work?

Comment: @BetunHerreraAlanis, I updated the answer, Please check it if it can helps.

Comment: Now it seems to fully work, i added an xml in the pro directory with the modification you told me and so far it works (Tested on 4 devices so far). Seems like this is solved, thanks a lot for your help.